# Issues of Image overlay after Render in Grease Pencil

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

Please check the Screenshot, where I am facing the issue of image overlay after Render in Grease pencil. The Scarf is over the character but after render the scarf goes back of the Character. The left hand side is the Blender file and right hand side is the Rendered image.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering, enable the Z Pass option, and make sure that objects origins (both mesh and Grease Pencil objects) have the same location.

If this doesn't solve, please upload the file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.