Grease pencil object appearing in front of imported image planes, how to fix?
The grease pencil object always appears in front of imported image planes but this problem doesn't happen for regular planes. I tried unchecking the "in front" option on the grease pencil objects but that didn't fix it. I also tried selecting alpha clip which but that got rid of the alpha gradients in the objects which I want to keep. The pink and gray circles are the imported images and the person is the grease pencil object. 

Hello and welcome. I had the same problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/326889/why-does-imported-video-not-show-up-in-my-render-in-front-of-grease-pencil-fill and the fix was this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310280/issues-of-image-overlay-after-render-in-grease-pencil
