Why does imported video not show up in my render in front of Grease Pencil fill?
In Blender 4.2.3 2D Animation in Object Mode I add a video using Shift+A > Image > Mesh Plane in front of the blue fill Grease Pencil object. You can see it clearly is in front of the blue fill background Grease Pencil object.

When pressing Numpad 0 you can see the preview.

But when I render using F12, the video does not show up.

But if I remove the Grease Pencil object then render, then it works and I can see the video. What gives? Is this a bug or is there a setting I am missing? Also I noticed that the video FPS does not go with the FPS I set for the entire project. Or is my workflow incorrect, is there another way I'm supposed to add the video?

It looks like the Grease Pencils always appear in front of the video:

Here's the render output:


For the video FPS vs. project FPS: the FPS setting in a video file is used for playback for example in video players. Neverthelesss, a video has a certain number of frames - and in Blender (unless you do not modify anthing), per Timeline frame one frame of the video will be played. And if you have a 120 second video at 25 FPS, this will have 3000 frames. If your Blender scene is set to 30 FPS, the video's 3000 frames will result in 100 seconds of animation playback.

However, if you are in video editing and import a movie clip into a strip, Blender will automatically set the scene's FPS to match the FPS of the imported video. This only happens upon the first import. If you import a second movie afterwards with a different FPS, the scene will keep the setting from the first movie. Even deleting all clips and then directly importing the second will not change the scene's FPS anymore, the automatic changing only works on the very first import.

@GordonBrinkmann btw thanks for sharing the link that solved my problem. Yes my solution was to re-encode the fps of the video to 24 using ffmpeg -i in.webm -r 24 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4 then I set the fps of Blender to 24 so it's consistent and all in sync.

Well, re-encoding is one solution, I think it's always depending on the "direction" (higher to lower FPS or lower to higher) and how much difference is between be two framerates... the quality of the video can suffer a bit... I usually decide to simply use the video FPS in my Blender scene as well so that I can keep the original video data.
